# Public Google calendar showing wrong time zone (GMT)

Tags: google-calendar, time-zone

I have a Google calendar of events for our local elementary school. I've made a month view publicly viewable, but it shows events in GMT rather than in US/Eastern timezone.

My settings and the calendar's settings have the time zone set properly.

Why is this showing in GMT?

Is there a way to explicitly set the time zone for display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the link to the view had an explicit time zone of UTC as a query parameter. It's odd because I never put it there and (I'm pretty sure) it used to work properly.

Comment: i was just fighting this myself, being logged in to multiple accounts means clicking a link goes to the default account calendar so was trying to add manually using a link, ended up being that I was doing 'From URL' (which worked and added the calendar) and GMT is the default, but when I used 'Subscribe' and edited out the protocol and domain it worked and used the correct timezone

Answer (score 2):

In calendar properties you can set it up there when you share it.  Are these events yours or someone else adding them, which may account for the GMT?

Answer (score 1):

If you click settings under the calendar, you should be able to set time zones and other localisation settings.

If the shared calendar is the only one showing incorrectly, maybe you have to login to the account that is sharing it and change it there.

Comment: The account's settings and the calendar's settings have the time zone set properly.

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain exactly which sort of "month view" you've made publicly available? (A URL would be ideal :) Are you looking at actual web pages, or is this a calendar feed of some description?

Single occurrence events are stored as UTC, so that may be what you're seeing if you're looking at relatively raw data.

If you're embedding the calendar using an iframe (via the "Embed this Calendar" option) then you need to set the time zone there, too. If you follow the link saying "Customize the color, size and other options" (or something similar) there's a time zone option in the bottom left.

Answer (score 1):

Update your HTML code in [Embed This Calendar]

1. From your site.google, **Remove** your previous "Public Google calendars"
2. Go to Calendar Settings
3. Select Calendars tab
4. Click your calendar account (your Gmail)
5. Click "Customize the color, size, and other options"
6. Check mark all calendars
7. Select "Time Zone"
8. Update HTMT (locate on top right corner)
9. Copy all of the HTML strings (codes) in the box
10. Paste these code into your website (Step 5, right side)
11. Save
12. Now you can re-insert your calendars into site.google